# Flowing tears on moving head

Tags: armature, fluid-simulation

As the title says, I want to have tears flowing from a pair of eyes but I seem to not know how. What I tried was to have a domain cube cover the head, the head (which isn't a separate mesh from the rest of the body) be the obstacle, and two inflow spheres (3 segs x 3 rings) for each eye corner, but the domain cube doesn't change shape. Have not linked the domain to the head bone or started animating the armature just yet. Started by seeing if it could be done. So, what is the best way to make tears flow from eyes and run down the cheeks?

For reference, the body mesh size is about 0.4 x 0.6 x 0.2, and the inflows' sizes were like 0.001.

Comment: How big is your domain? Make sure you Apply Scale on each of your Domain, Inflow, Obstacle meshes and that your domain resolution is set high enough for you inflows to be significant - the resolution indicates the number of fluid cells along the domain’s largest dimension so should be more than `domainsize/0.001` in your case.

Comment: @RichSedman The inflow and domains were sized the moment they were created. Domain was 0.1 in radius. As for the body, I couldn't find "Apply Scale" in the Search for either mesh or armature. However, I did create the inflow sphere again and this time a size of 0.005 and I got a flow. The moment I turned the body into an obstacle my computer died.

Comment: Use Ctrl+A to Apply Scale. The Resolution defines how big the cells of the simulation are - they’ll have to be smaller than your tear inflow so if domain it 0.5 and inflow is 0.005 you’ll need resolution of 100 *minimum* (that will make for a really poor simulation - you want to look for much higher resolution - perhaps, say 10x the expecter tear size). But that high resolution will likely require more memory than you have - hence the crash. Make the domain as small as possible and apply scale after resize. Before baking simulation check how much memory it says it requires too.